# XSLT to change the child node only when other child node attribute is present

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to change the XML file where peci:Organization is a repeated child node.
I need to make change that if <peci:Organization_Type = 'Alternate_Cost_Center' is present in file, then change this to <peci:Organization_Type = 'Cost_Center' and change <peci:Organization_Type = 'Cost_Center' to <peci:Organization_Type = 'Dummy_Cost_Center'.
I need to do this only when `<peci:Organization_Type = 'Alternate_Cost_Center'` is present in file for an employee.

I have been trying below code:

```
-----enter code here---
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    xmlns:is="java:com.workday.esb.intsys.xpath.ParsedIntegrationSystemFunctions"
    xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci" xmlns:this="urn:this-stylesheet"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xdiff="urn:com.workday/esb/xdiff"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:op="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" version="2.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl wd this xsd op xdiff peci xsi is">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="peci:Organization_Type">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test=". = 'Alternate_Cost_Center'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'Cost_Center'" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test=". = 'Cost_Center'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="'Dummy_Cost_Center'" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="." />
                    </xsl:otherwise>    
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

```
**Example XML:**
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    
    -<peci:Worker_Effective_Stack_Aggregate xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci">
    -<peci:Workers_Effective_Stack>
    -<peci:Summary>     <peci:Integration_Event>da1c439dcf86011a442a9562d9960000</peci:Integration_Event>    
    <peci:Integration_Sent_On>20211121T07:52:23</peci:Integration_Sent_On>    <peci:Payroll_Company_ID>Payroll_Company_Jabil_Switzerland</peci:Payroll_Company_ID>
       <peci:Payroll_Company_Name>Jabil - Switzerland</peci:Payroll_Company_Name>
        <peci:Payroll_Company_Code>5200</peci:Payroll_Company_Code>
        <peci:Pay_Group_ID>C1</peci:Pay_Group_ID>
        <peci:Pay_Group_Name>CHE - Monthly - 5200</peci:Pay_Group_Name>
        <peci:Pay_Group_Country>CH</peci:Pay_Group_Country>
        <peci:Pay_Group_Code>C1</peci:Pay_Group_Code>
        <peci:Pay_Period_Start>20211101</peci:Pay_Period_Start>
        <peci:Pay_Period_End>20211130</peci:Pay_Period_End>
        <peci:Updated_From>20210601T10:25:54</peci:Updated_From>
        <peci:Updated_To>20211121T07:52:23</peci:Updated_To>
        <peci:Effective_From>20211101</peci:Effective_From>
        <peci:Effective_To>20211130</peci:Effective_To>
        <peci:Change_Detection>Include only changes entered since the last successful run.</peci:Change_Detection>       <peci:First_Primary_Run_of_Pay_Period>0</peci:First_Primary_Run_of_Pay_Period>
     <peci:Ad_Hoc_Run>1</peci:Ad_Hoc_Run>
        <peci:Full_Snapshot>0</peci:Full_Snapshot>
        <peci:Worker_Count>1</peci:Worker_Count>    
    <peci:Version>1</peci:Version>    
    </peci:Summary>        
    -<peci:Worker>    
    -<peci:Worker_Summary>    
    <peci:WID>4d73f467a8440137745f162288014b40</peci:WID>    
    <peci:Employee_ID>3062905</peci:Employee_ID>
    <peci:Name>Anna Conti</peci:Name>    
    </peci:Worker_Summary>        
    -<peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="0">    
    <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>    
    <peci:Effective_Moment>19000101T00:00:00</peci:Effective_Moment>
    <peci:Entry_Moment>20211109T10:17:13</peci:Entry_Moment>        
    -<peci:Position peci:isUpdated="1">    
    <peci:Position_ID>P3341022</peci:Position_ID>
     <peci:Position_Time_Type>Full_time</peci:Position_Time_Type>    
    <peci:Job_Profile>51016106</peci:Job_Profile>        
    -<peci:Supervisor>
       <peci:ID>2115831</peci:ID>    
    <peci:Name>Damian Gruber</peci:Name>    
    </peci:Supervisor>
    -<peci:Organization>
      <peci:Organization_Type>Cost_Center</peci:Organization_Type>
        <peci:Organization_Code>30900498</peci:Organization_Code>    
    <peci:Organization_Name>General Above Site</peci:Organization_Name>    
    </peci:Organization>    
    -<peci:Organization>    
    <peci:Organization_Type>Alternate_Cost_Center</peci:Organization_Type>    
    <peci:Organization_Code>31020420</peci:Organization_Code>    
    <peci:Organization_Name>JJMD - Finance Europe</peci:Organization_Name>    
    </peci:Organization>    
        -<peci:Organization peci:isUpdated="1">
        <peci:Organization_Type>Pay_Group</peci:Organization_Type>
        <peci:Organization_Code peci:isAdded="1">C1</peci:Organization_Code>
        <peci:Organization_Name>CHE - Monthly -5200</peci:Organization_Name>
        </peci:Organization>
       -<peci:Organization>
        <peci:Organization_Type>Supervisory</peci:Organization_Type>
        <peci:Organization_Code>2202783</peci:Organization_Code>    
<peci:Organization_Name>Financial Planning Analysis</peci:Organization_Name>
        </peci:Organization>
            -<peci:Organization>    
    <peci:Organization_Type>Company</peci:Organization_Type>    
    <peci:Organization_Code>5200</peci:Organization_Code>    <peci:Organization_Name>Jabil Switzerland Manufacturing GmbH</peci:Organization_Name>
        </peci:Organization>    
    <ptdf:HR_Admin xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf">N</ptdf:HR_Admin>    
    <ptdf:Position_Name xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf">Sr. Financial Analyst</ptdf:Position_Name>    
    <ptdf:Job_Profile_Name xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf">Sr. Financial Analyst</ptdf:Job_Profile_Name>    
    <ptdf:Employee_Group xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf">1</ptdf:Employee_Group>
        <ptdf:Employee_Subgroup xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf">C1</ptdf:Employee_Subgroup>
        <ptdf:Personnel_Area xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf">C210</ptdf:Personnel_Area>
    <ptdf:Personnel_SubArea xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf">5204</ptdf:Personnel_SubArea>
    <ptdf:Business_Area xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf">5204</ptdf:Business_Area>
        <ptdf:Work_Schedule xmlns:ptdf="urn:com.workday/peci/tdf">S540000</ptdf:Work_Schedule>
        </peci:Position>
        -<peci:Additional_Information>
        <peci:WorkerID>4d73f467a8440137745f162288014b40</peci:WorkerID>
        </peci:Additional_Information>
        </peci:Effective_Change>
       -<peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="1">
        <peci:Derived_Event_Code>HIR-R</peci:Derived_Event_Code>    
    <peci:Effective_Moment>20210801T00:00:00</peci:Effective_Moment>    
    <peci:Entry_Moment>20210818T02:26:42</peci:Entry_Moment>
            -<peci:Worker_Status>    
    <peci:Status>Active</peci:Status>    
    <peci:Active>0</peci:Active>    
    <peci:Active_Status_Date>20210801</peci:Active_Status_Date>    
    <peci:Terminated>0</peci:Terminated>    
    <peci:Hire_Date>20210801</peci:Hire_Date>    
    <peci:Original_Hire_Date>20210816</peci:Original_Hire_Date> <peci:Hire_Reason>General_Event_Subcategory_New_Hire_Replacement</peci:Hire_Reason>
    <peci:Continuous_Service_Date>20210801</peci:Continuous_Service_Date>
    <peci:First_Day_of_Work>20210801</peci:First_Day_of_Work>
    <peci:Seniority_Date>20210816</peci:Seniority_Date>
    </peci:Worker_Status>
    -<peci:Additional_Information>
    <peci:WorkerID>4d73f467a8440137745f162288014b40</peci:WorkerID>
    </peci:Additional_Information>
    </peci:Effective_Change>
    <peci:Effective_Change peci:Sequence="2">    
    <peci:Derived_Event_Code>HIR</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
        <peci:Effective_Moment>20210816T00:00:00</peci:Effective_Moment>    
    <peci:Entry_Moment>20210818T02:26:42</peci:Entry_Moment>        
    -<peci:Worker_Status peci:isUpdated="1">    
    <peci:Status>Active</peci:Status>    
    <peci:Active peci:priorValue="0">1</peci:Active>    
    <peci:Active_Status_Date peci:priorValue="20210801">20210816</peci:Active_Status_Date>    
    <peci:Terminated>0</peci:Terminated>    
    <peci:Hire_Date peci:priorValue="20210801">20210816</peci:Hire_Date>    
    <peci:Original_Hire_Date peci:priorValue="20210801">20210816</peci:Original_Hire_Date> <peci:Hire_Reason>General_Event_Subcategory_New_Hire_Replacement</peci:Hire_Reason>
    <peci:Continuous_Service_Date peci:priorValue="20210801">20210816</peci:Continuous_Service_Date>
    <peci:First_Day_of_Work peci:priorValue="20210801">20210816</peci:First_Day_of_Work>
    <peci:Seniority_Date peci:priorValue="20210801">20210816</peci:Seniority_Date>
    </peci:Worker_Status>
    </peci:Effective_Change>
    </peci:Worker>
    </peci:Workers_Effective_Stack>
    </peci:Worker_Effective_Stack_Aggregate>
```

---

**Expected Output:**

```
-<peci:Organization>
<peci:Organization_Type>Dummy_Cost_Center</peci:Organization_Type>
<peci:Organization_Code>30900498</peci:Organization_Code>
<peci:Organization_Name>General Above Site</peci:Organization_Name>
</peci:Organization>
-<peci:Organization>
<peci:Organization_Type>Cost_Center</peci:Organization_Type>
<peci:Organization_Code>31020420</peci:Organization_Code>
<peci:Organization_Name>JJMD - Finance Europe</peci:Organization_Name>
</peci:Organization>
```

My XSLT code is working fine when `<peci:Organization_Type>Alternate_Cost_Center</peci:Organization_Type>` is present.
But when it is not present even then `<peci:Organization_Type>Cost_Center</peci:Organization_Type>` getting changed to Dummy_Cost_Center.
I do not want this, I want to make change only when `peci:Organization_Type>Alternate_Cost_Center</peci:Organization_Type>` is present for employee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to write the below `xslt` code, which is working for my requirements:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:etv="urn:com.workday/etv" xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci" xmlns:this="urn:this-stylesheet" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xtt="urn:com.workday/xtt" exclude-result-prefixes="xs this" version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="peci:Worker/peci:Effective_Change/peci:Position/peci:Organization[peci:Organization_Type = 'Cost_Center']/peci:Organization_Type">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="exists(current()/../../peci:Organization[peci:Organization_Type = 'Alternate_Cost_Center'])">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="'Dummy_Cost_Center'" />
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:value-of select="'Cost_Center'" />
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="peci:Worker/peci:Effective_Change/peci:Position/peci:Organization[peci:Organization_Type = 'Alternate_Cost_Center']/peci:Organization_Type">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="'Cost_Center'" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by simply using two "replace" templates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    xmlns:is="java:com.workday.esb.intsys.xpath.ParsedIntegrationSystemFunctions"
    xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci" xmlns:this="urn:this-stylesheet"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xdiff="urn:com.workday/esb/xdiff"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:op="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" version="2.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xsl wd this xsd op xdiff peci xsi is">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />
    
    <!-- Identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="peci:Organization[peci:Organization_Type='Alternate_Cost_Center']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <peci:Organization_Type>Cost_Center</peci:Organization_Type>
            <xsl:copy-of select="peci:*[name()!='peci:Organization_Type']" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="peci:Organization[peci:Organization_Type='Cost_Center' and //peci:Organization_Type='Alternate_Cost_Center']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <peci:Organization_Type>Dummy_Cost_Center</peci:Organization_Type>
            <xsl:copy-of select="peci:*[name()!='peci:Organization_Type']" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output should be as expected.
These two templates match the desired elements with a predicate if, and only if, the `peci:Organization_Type` matches the desired value. Otherwise just the *Identity template* is executed.

**EDIT:**
Now the second template is only executed if there is an `Organization_Type='Alternate_Cost_Center'` node present **in the whole file**. If you need to check for this node only *on the same level*, use the following template-match-rule instead:

```
<xsl:template match="peci:Organization[peci:Organization_Type='Cost_Center' and ../peci:Organization/peci:Organization_Type='Alternate_Cost_Center']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <peci:Organization_Type>Dummy_Cost_Center</peci:Organization_Type>
        <xsl:copy-of select="peci:*[name()!='peci:Organization_Type']" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi, This will change the peci:Organization_Type Cost Center to Dummy Cost center, event if Alternate Cost Center is not present...... So my requirement is that when only Cost Center is present then nothing should happen,  and this XSLT runs only when Alternate Cost Center is present. I hope I am able to communicate this problem.

Comment: I updated my answer to better reflect your requirements. Now `Cost Center` is only changed if there is an `Alternative Cost Center` present in either the file or at the same level.